# Comparing Algorithm Strategies

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, data-structures

Are **Brute Force Algorithm** and **Exhaustive Search** both references to the same ideas?

Comment: Please don't abuse tags. This has nothing to do with computability.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Both refer to the idea of basically trying every possible combination to check whether the desired output is met. One is called exhaustive search because we search over every possible combination till combinations are "exhausted". Brute force is basically the same idea by trying every combination as well without any optimizations or clever algorithms. We are basically using the force the computer to solve a problem.